# How to read a file from "open With" option of File Explorer?

Tags: c#, wpf

Most of the cases we use (as beginner) OpenFileDialog to open File explorer and we choose files...

But I want, if we right click on the file and choose "open with" option and choose the WPF app, then how it can be read?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file will be sent to your application as a command-line parameter. You can read `Environment.CommandLine` and other variants to read the value of the parameter and take action accordingly.

If you're using WPF, you may want to catch `Startup` event and use `e.Args` therein to get access to the command line parameters passed in. You can see an example of that [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/wpf-application/command-line-parameters/).

To know more about how Windows sends command-line parameters to the applications, see [this excellent MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: If history is any guide, that excellent MSDN article will be somewhere else by this time next year.